# Sending JSON to PHP file and Recieving Response in JS

Tags: javascript, php, json

I have looked at many other questions on here and I have tried many different methods but none seem to work.

Heres my javascript file

```
function sendData() {
     var jsondata;
     var j = {"pub_id":"'+pid+'","a_type":"'+a_t'","p_domain":"'+domain+'"}
     var str_j = JSON.stringify(j);

     var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("POST", "https://ads.schlarman.org/zz.php", !0);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
     xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
         jsondata = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
         console.log(jsondata);
       }
     }
}
sendData();
```

then zz.php

```
<?php 
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $json_decode = json_decode($json, true);
   $json_encode = json_encode($json_decode);
   echo $json_encode;
?>
```

Comment: How does it fail exactly? Would love a little more detail about the error(s) you're getting.

Comment: Invalid JSON to begin with.

Comment: `$json_decode = json_decode($json, true);` strikes me as kind of an odd thing to do.

Comment: @snapjs I didnt get any response from the PHP file, not even an error

Comment: @PHPglue Still new to all of this and I was reading and thats how it was said to be done. I is including Javascript Varibles

Comment: @TimMorton This is based on just hours of looking at stackoverflow and blogs, I am just trying to get a response from the PHP file. Thats what I read about and it said that it would get a response but it doesnt seem to be working whatsoever

Comment: Use browser's console to see if your data is even being posted.  The console is your friend; it will let you see if there is any response.  Check error logs.  Try commenting out the header command and see if the page responds with an error message.  You will be able to see it in the console.

Comment: var j = {"pub_id":"'+pid+'","a_type":"'+a_t'","p_domain":"'+domain+'"} is missing a + after +a_t. Your javascript execution is probably dying right there

Comment: Actually, I shouldn't have called it the console.  I actually mean developer's tools->network

Comment: @TimMorton Eventually I figured out that a typo was causing it to call an older version of the file but I got it to get the right file but now I get this error in the console `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://ads.schlarman.org/zz.php. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).`

Comment: AJAX has to go to the same domain that called it.  Google that error message.  I assumed you were working with your own website.

Comment: @TimMorton I am trying to make this so it is able to be called from different domains and connect to mine

Comment: OK, you'll have to research CORS.  I don't have experience with that.  But first, are you serving up the javascript in a page from your server, or from a file?  That could perhaps trigger the cross origin issue.  If you're serving it from the same domain, you shouldn't be getting that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If at all possible, build your json strings from *actual* javascript arrays/objects

```
var j = {"pub_id":"'+pid+'","a_type":"'+a_t'","p_domain":"'+domain+'"};
```

could & probably *should* be

```
var j = {"pub_id": pid, "a_type": a_t, "p_domain": domain};
```

Also, try adding the following header to your php

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

More info here: https://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Thanks! I finally got a response from the zz.php file. Does this open up security issue though?

Comment: You're very welcome. As for a security issue, yes. You might want to use: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://yourdomain.com`.